# How to properly model bind json with sub-objects to ASP.NET MVC ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, model-binding

Given the following client side code fragment:

```
var vm = {
  Input : "Label: Value",
  Rules : [
    { Name : "RemoveString",
      Params : [
        "Label: "
      ]
    }
  ]
};

$.post("/API/ApplyRule", vm, function(data) { });
```

And the following ViewModel on server side:

```
[Serializable]
public class ApplyRuleRequestViewModel
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public List<RuleViewModel> Rules { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class RuleViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Params { get; set; }
}
```

And the following controller code:

```
public class APIController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ApplyRule(ApplyRuleRequestViewModel model)
    {
        //Problem here... model is not fully deserialized into the ViewModel object.
        return View();
    }
}
```

I am having a problem trying to serialize the Rules portion of the client side ViewModel.  When debugging the code at the controller line above that said //Problem..., I see that the top level object properties made it, but not the sub-object. So, I get something like:

```
var vm = new ApplyRuleRequestViewModel {
  Input = "Label: Value",
  Rules = new List<RuleViewModel> {
     new RuleViewModel { Name = null, Parameters = null }
  }
}
```

I am expecting something like:

```
var vm = new ApplyRuleRequestViewModel {
  Input = "Label: Value",
  Rules = new List<RuleViewModel> {
     new RuleViewModel { 
         Name = "RemoveString", 
         Parameters = new List<string> { "Label: " }
     }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Why is it not binding the Rules array properly?

Do you need to create your own custom model binder to bind this properly?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your message as JSON.

```
var vm = {
  Input : "Label: Value",
  Rules : [
    { Name : "RemoveString",
      Params : [
        "Label: "
      ]
    }
  ]
};

$.postJson("/API/ApplyRule", vm, function(data) { }); // See below for definition of `.postJson`.
```

The last argument `json` will set the accepts header to indicate JSON is wanted. The  default model binder should automatically interact with the built-in `JsonValueProviderFactory` to properly read the structured message.

**EDIT** Missed something. You need to set the `contentType`, so `.post` as it stands may not work.

Here's a helper method for posting JSON (not just POSTING and *receiving* json, as post would do).

```
$.postJson = function(url, data, success) {
  $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: success
        }); 
}
```